# Why is this loop not running?

Tags: python

```
n=int(input("Kiek elementų turės tavo sąrašas"))
A=[]
n=0
t=0
teig=int(input("Įvesk teigiamą elementą kurį noprėsi pridėti prie sąrašo"))
neig=int(input("Įvesk neigiamą elementą kurį norėsi pridėti prie sąrašo"))
for a in range(1,n+1): # HERE #########
    t=int(input("Įvesk %i masyvo elementą"%(a)))
    A.append(t)**
for x in A:
    if x>0:
        t=t+1
    else:
        n=n+1
if n<t:
    a=t-n
else:
    a=n-t
for x in range(1,a+1):
    if n<t:
        A.append(teig)
    else:
        A.append(neig)
```

Why is the marked loop not working? I don't get input line for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say `range(1, n+1)` when `n=0`. The `range(1, 1)` is empty, so the loop never executes. Increase `n`.

Answer (score 1):

`n = 0` so `range(1,n+1)` is `range(1,1)` which when iterated over is equivalent to `[]` thus the loop body never occurs.

You need to remove the assignment `n = 0` so that the value read from the user is used instead.

Comment: It's not necessarily Python 2, so we don't know that the `range` is a list. ;-)

Comment: Tell me one place that you can't replace `range(1,1)` with `[]`? I could have said it was `iter([])`.

Answer (score 1):

You have `for a in range(1,n+1):` and `n=0` so it's `range(1,1)` which is `[]`

Comment: It's not necessarily Python 2, so we don't know that the `range` is a list. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Make your code simpler :

```
for a in range(1,1):
    print("ok")
```

Doesn't work .

```
for a in range(1,2):
    print("ok")
```

Works :)
So, you may have a logic issue when writing your loops.

Answer (score 0):

You are cycling from 1 to n+1, but n+1 is 1. 
range(1, 1) is a empty list, so no iteration will be performed.